# Django template pass array increase counter value inside template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to pass array value counter value inside Django template.

```
{% for scene in scenes %}

    <hotspot name="skin_btn_prev{{forloop.counter}}"  
    name1="{{ iterator.next }}" keep="false"       
    style="skin_hotspotstyle_navigate"  
    ath="-180" x="55"    y="0"  
    scale="0.5" alpha="0.5" 
    linkedscene="{{scenes.1.dbobj.getStrID}}"  
    onclick="lookat(0, 34, 120);" />

{% endfor %}
```

**linkedscene="{{scenes.1.dbobj.getStrID}}"**

I want to pass here the counter value.

when I run the for loop here I want to pass the value like 1,2,3,4,5....till last loop run.

How can I do this?

Comment: is this {{scenes.1.dbobj.getStrID}} an attribute of scenes?

Comment: yes these are the attribute .I Just want to pass the counter variable value at the place of 1.

Comment: Do you need a particular ID or just any value starting from one till the end of the loop? If second one, then it's just `{{ forsloop.counter }}`

Comment: I need the particular id like 5, 8,9,10,11.... It was random ID.